# Swift 4 integration with unity3d 5.6.6f2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, swift4

I'm trying to integration Unity project with iOS (Swift) native project, by following [this tutorial](https://www.agnosticdev.com/blog-entry/swift/integrating-unity-and-vuforia-ios-swift-project).

However, I'm not getting the expected result. A black screen appears and it logs the following ِerror message:

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:
>   -[UIApplication delegate] PID: 3383, TID: 901726, Thread name: UnityGfxDeviceWorker, Queue name:
>   com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21

I am using:

1. Unity version 2018.1.6f1.
2. Xcode version 9.3 4.
3. Swift version.

Also, I tried to use [ios-unity5](https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5), but I got the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it 's a issue with the special release 2017 in Unity and the issue was solved in the new release 2018

[issuetracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios11-api-called-on-a-background-thread-uiapplication-delegate-unitycurrentorientation-on-launch-in-an-empty-project)